# why a hidden column will be set as optional if i change its defualt value

Tags: content-type, form, site-column, default-value, hidden

Sometimes you are faced with problems that you can not understand . Now I have a hidden column inside my Issue tracking list, which is used to store a series of string to be read by the list workflow. now i set a defualt value for the column such as "ABC", and i set it as a hidden field, so user will not be able to modify its value or see it. but the problem is that if admin users chnage the defualt value of the hidden field from the "List Option>> List Setting >> Columns >> click on the hidden column", then its type inside the content type will be changed from hidden to optional and the field will appear inside the New and edit forms ,, so can any one adivce on this please? is there a way to prevent the hidden column from being set as optional when its defualt value is changed ?
Thanks